# Error executing php files after upgrading to mac os x Mavericks 10.9

Tags: php, macos, phpunit, osx-mavericks, zend-server

After upgrading to 10.9 Mavericks I get the errors below when trying to run php scripts.

*I am using Zend Server and have disabled the default httpd and php. Everything was working fine before the upgrade.*

**Examples:**

**phpunit:**

```
/usr/local/bin/phpunit: line 2: ?php: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/phpunit: line 3: /Applications: is a directory
/usr/local/bin/phpunit: line 4: LICENSE.html: command not found
/usr/local/bin/phpunit: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/usr/local/bin/phpunit: line 5: ` * Copyright (c) 2001-2013, Sebastian Bergmann <sebastian@phpunit.de>.'
```

**phpcs**

```
/usr/local/zend/bin/phpcs: line 2: ?php: No such file or directory
/usr/local/zend/bin/phpcs: line 3: /Applications: is a directory
/usr/local/zend/bin/phpcs: line 4: LICENSE.html: command not found
/usr/local/zend/bin/phpcs: line 5: LICENSE.html: command not found
/usr/local/zend/bin/phpcs: line 6: LICENSE.html: command not found
/usr/local/zend/bin/phpcs: line 7: LICENSE.html: command not found
/usr/local/zend/bin/phpcs: line 8: LICENSE.html: command not found
/usr/local/zend/bin/phpcs: line 9: LICENSE.html: command not found
/usr/local/zend/bin/phpcs: line 10: LICENSE.html: command not found
/usr/local/zend/bin/phpcs: line 11: syntax error near unexpected token newline
/usr/local/zend/bin/phpcs: line 11: ` * @author    Greg Sherwood <gsherwood@squiz.net>'
```

**If I run  /usr/local/zend/bin/php /usr/local/bin/phpunit or  /usr/local/zend/bin/php /usr/local/bin/phpcs it works**

**Other details:**

$PATH
-bash: /opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/zend/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/zend/bin: No such file or directory

Comment: Whats the error message ?

Comment: What I wrote in the description. Instead of executing the php file using php looks like it's executing it using bash.

Answer (score 0):

It appears your command line PHP has moved.

Try `which phpunit` and open up the file in vi or similar. In the first line it says where it expects php to be. Either you change the first line in those two files (phpunit and phpcs) to

```
#!/usr/local/zend/bin php
```

or you create a symlink at the referenced location to /usr/local/zend/bin/php

Let me know if you need help with any of those 2 steps.

Comment: It's not that. The first line references the correct path to the php file. It looks like it's running the file with bash instead of php. If I say php /usr/local/zend/bin/phpcs it works but with just phpcs I get that error.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround by replacing the top line `#!/usr/local/zend/bin/php` with the following:

`#!/usr/bin/env /usr/local/zend/bin/php`